# How to transform a data frame (table) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I re-arrange a table.  I have the following data frame:

```
        1_3         red     0.988
        1_3         blue    0.020
        2_5         red     0.110
        2_5         green   0.299
        4_6         red     0.349
        4_6         blue    0.750
```

Now, I want to rearrange this table so that the list of files is on the x-axis and the colors on the y-axis, like the table below.

```
             1_3        2_5     4_6
red         0.988       0.110       0.349
blue        0.020       0.000       0.750
green       0.000       0.299       0.000
```

I’ve tried to use the dcast function but it requires a FUN entry, otherwise it defaults to length unless I apply a function to the columns. Something tells me I'm missing something about dcast. Any thoughts?

This is what I've applied to the table. The following line generates an error regarding the FUN.  If I remove it, the dcast says I need a function.

```
  dcast(color ~ file, value.var = "freq", fill = 0, FUN = NULL)
```

Comment: Does it have any column names?

Comment: No headers needed.  But, the data frame file has "file", "color", "freq".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `FUN` argument, it is `fun.aggregate`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, color ~ file, value.var = "freq", fill = 0, fun.aggregate = NULL)
#. color   1_3   2_5   4_6
#1  blue 0.020 0.000 0.750
#2 green 0.000 0.299 0.000
#3   red 0.988 0.110 0.349
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(file = c("1_3", "1_3", "2_5", "2_5", "4_6", "4_6"
), color = c("red", "blue", "red", "green", "red", "blue"), freq = c(0.988, 
0.02, 0.11, 0.299, 0.349, 0.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Correct. My bad. I forgot to include it in the post.  My original data has it.  I get the following error:  "Error in .fun(.value[i], ...) :  2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1.
Not sure what this is trying to tell me.

Comment: Let me check my own code.  I wonder if I'm introducing something unintended.

Comment: I had mispelled "aggregate".  If anything, my approach was sound.  Your suggestion worked.  Thank you very much.